# Global step not incrementing with batch norm and custom estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I have a customer estimator that has several layers that look like the following in the model function:

```
natural_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs = natural_layer, 
                                units = units, 
                                activation = None,
                                use_bias = False,
                                kernel_regularizer = params['regularizer'],
                                name = 'pre_batch_norm_layer_' + str(i + 1))

natural_layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(natural_layer,
                                              axis = 1,
                                              center = True,
                                              scale = True,
                                              training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
                                              name = 'batch_norm_layer_' + str(i + 1))

natural_layer = params['natural_layer_activation'](natural_layer, name = 'activation_layer_' + str(i + 1))
```

Because I'm using batch norm, the training op is set up like this:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.MultitaskOptimizerWrapper(params['optimization_algorithm'](params['training_rate']))
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step = tf.train.get_global_step())
```

Where the optimizer is usually tf.train.AdamOptimizer.

However, when I go to train the estimator the global step never increments (so training will run forever), and I get this:

WARNING:tensorflow:It seems that global step (tf.train.get_global_step) has not been increased. Current value (could be stable): 0 vs previous value: 0. You could increase the global step by passing tf.train.get_global_step() to Optimizer.apply_gradients or Optimizer.minimize.

I am passing tf.train.get_global_step() to minimize, so I'm not sure why it never gets updated. My hunch is that it has something to do with the batch normalization because when I remove that or replace it with dropout, everything works fine (even when keeping the update ops lines that are required for batch normalization per the documentation).

Anyone know what is going on? Happy to post more code if helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why the global step was not incrementing automatically, but manually incrementing the global step as follows by adding it to the train_op with tf.group is a nice work around.

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.MultitaskOptimizerWrapper(params['optimization_algorithm'](params['training_rate']))
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

        global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
        update_global_step = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1, name = 'update_global_step')

        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss = loss, train_op = tf.group(train_op, update_global_step))
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue even without batch normalization. From what I remember, I was able to get around it by calling `update_ops` in `sess.run` along with `train_ops`, as opposed to in a `tf.control_dependencies` clause. This probably is just a bug with tensorflow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to completely solve the problem, but a suspiciously similar problem arises when both defining an op and adding it to a collection in a `tf.cond`. In fact, it seems that this bug shuts down _any_ of the update_ops collection from being run. It may be interesting to [take a look](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14699).